# Как сделать портативный лицензионный Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Можно ли установить портативный Windows 10 и активировать его ключом? Подразумевается установка из официального образа, а не какой-то левой сборки.

Как это должно происходить? Смущают следующие моменты:

- При активации не произойдёт ли привязка ключа к железу того компа, с которого делается установка?
- Как при установке получить оба загрузчика - для классического bios и для uefi?
- При использовании на другом компьютере с совместимостью с железом и с драйверами всё будет хорошо? Или он будет докачивать их из интернета по мере необходимости?

Предпочтительна именно полноценная установка с возможностью доустанавливать программы, но готов рассмотреть и другие варианты.

Comment: Теоретически: ставим статически, активируем, конвертируем в образ (wim, iso, vhd, etc.), копируем на флешку с дуальной загрузкой (как сделано на разного рода resque flash), используем. Как это будет практически - не пробовал.

Answer (score 2):

Стоит перейти на сайт производителя и внимательно прочесть [ограничения по использованию WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro#limitations).
Прямым текстом сказано, что PE: только для целей **разработки и восстановления**.

Использование PE как **встраиваемой ОС - недопустимо**. Для этого есть другие системы типа Embedded.
Для этого производитель установил **неотключаемое ограничение периода работы в 72 часа**.

Таким образом, использование Windows PE в иных целях будет трактовано как нарушение лицензионного соглашения.

Comment: Но WinPE и Win10 - это же разные ОС и разные дистрибутивы? Я спрашивал про Win10.

Comment: Вопрос был про Portable режим - это режим PE. Вопрос про установку Windows на USB-носитель - это совсем **другой** вопрос. Но даже в этом случае допустимо использовать такой носитель только на 1-ом ПК из-за ограничений лицензии. И уточнение PE режим может быть использован для множества ОС фирмы Microsoft , начиная с WIndows 2000, как Server, так и Workstation (XP,7,Vista,8,8.1,10)

Comment: Под portable-режимом имелась в виду возможность втыкать в разные компы (хотя бы в 2), а не специальный дистрибутив.

Comment: Тогда уточните вопрос, я  про это прямо написал в **предыдущем** комментарии. И в этом случае Вам потребуется управлять лицензиями, например через сервер KMS. Не уверен, что для этого подойдут лицензии типа BOX или OEM. А это ответ на вопрос про [PE загрузчик](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-supported-platforms-and-cross-platform-deployments#firmware-bios-32-bit-and-64-bit)